# jQuery: Detect the position inside Flexbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have several boxes, using Flexbox as container and list tags as boxes inside. They're responsive and change position as you resize the width. I am trying to figure out a way via jQuery to detect which boxes are touching the left side and which are touching the right side so I can `addClass` of `right` or `left` to them based on their position for styling. I think it's possible using offset to achieve this which I'm figuring out how to start. Any ideas?

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/q31639o1/)

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    flex-direction: row;
    list-style:none;
}
li {
    border:10px salmon solid;
    padding: 25px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    background: white;
    flex-grow: 3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="container">
    <li>Alabama</li>
    <li>California</li>
    <li>Florida</li>
    <li>Idaho</li>
    <li>Kansas</li>
    <li>Nevada</li>
    <li>New York</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: " the right and left boxes" - what do you mean?

Comment: @nicael the left/right position of the boxes in the example.

Comment: Which boxes are touching the right side and which are touching the left side you mean?

Comment: "the left/right position of the boxes in the example. " - ??? where do you have boxes positioned to left / right?

Comment: Can I ask why you want to know when they are touching certain sides? I only ask because there might be an easier way than detecting that.

Comment: @nicael it's Flexbox, they're not positioned to left or right.

Comment: @ajmajmajma I need to remove the border-right for the boxes that touch the right side and border-left for those touch the left-side. Here I only added as an example, my full designed page is something else, but its purpose is the same.

Comment: @ajmajmajma I know it's possible to remove the mentioned border via CSS but I need a way with jQuery.

Comment: It is possible with jquery, you will have to just have a big listener - like what events are going to change this, the screen dragging? That is a pretty intense listener to use, in some browsers you will have to debounce it. I'm just trying to think if you could get around it in a much less complex fashion. Why do you have to pull off the borders from the sides? spacing issue? you could probably organize the css around it a little different to fix that.

Comment: To add to that - if you could show a fiddle with the behavior that is happening that you want to avoid, someone could probably help alot easier - because right now I can't really tell that you'd want to pull a border on a side off (or why you would want to).

Comment: @ajmajmajma Thanks... Yes I'm aware of the listener and I will use it carefully only within a width size. It's a complex design, all I need is to determine the boxes, if it wasn't flexbox it would be easier but it's responsive and it changes its position. There's no JS behavior to this in the real project, the example is pretty much it... What do you think?

Comment: I'm asking because if you are just pulling off the border on the left and right sides because of a spacing issue thing - you could use something like space-between or space-around instead instead of using borders to space between the items, then just set the background the color you want. Otherwise you're going to have to set up listeners on window scroll to detect lots of sizes - it wont be pretty.

Comment: Basically - is it because you want to fix spacing inside of the flex box? Because flex has some stuff built in to help you with that.

Comment: Thank you @ajmajmajma The answer by Makan worked well.

Comment: No problem, happy to try and help! just keep in mind that function is going to fire on every instance of window resize. You may still consider trying to find more elegant way around this problem. However, glad you could find what you needed!

Comment: @ajmajmajma totally understandable, this actually makes it half way what I need in the real project. After implementation it will be more efficient. Thanks for the heads up!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the jQuery code, place it at the bottom of your page:

```
(function(){
    function addClass(ul){
        ul.children('li.left').removeClass('left');
        ul.children('li.right').removeClass('right');

        $('ul > li:first-child').attr('class', 'left');
        $('ul > li:last-child').attr('class', 'right');

        var ulWidth = ul.width();
        var totalWidth = 0;

        ul.children('li').each(function () {
            totalWidth += ($(this).width() + 50);
            if (totalWidth > ulWidth) {
                $(this).addClass('left');
                $(this).prev().addClass('right');
                totalWidth = $(this).width();
            }
        });
    }

    var ul = $('ul.container');
    addClass(ul);

    $(window).on('resize', function(){
        addClass(ul);
    });
}());
```

Also the number 50 in the code is 'li' left and right padding and left and right border which adds up to 50. (15 + 15 + 10 + 10) Change it if needed.

Hope it helped!

Comment: Thanks Makan, great way. Testing it here https://jsfiddle.net/q31639o1/2/ the only thing that needs to be added is a listener so when the width is changed the classes get updated too.

Comment: Alright. Checkout the updated answer. It should work!

Comment: This works great! Thanks Makan, going line by line it all makes sense and a good work-around. Cheers!

Answer (score 3):

I created this little function that helped me do more tricks with variable width elements inside a flex parent container, hope it helps some of the people that hit this thread, jquery selectors are not performance-wise written so modify as per your needs:

```
function setFlexClasses(parent_selector) {

        //set parent jquery obj
        parent = $(parent_selector);

        //remove classes: flex-position-* , flex-row-*
        parent.find(' > div').removeClass (function (index, css) {
          return (css.match (/(^|\s)(flex-position-.*|flex-row-.*)\S+/g) || []).join(' ');
        });

        //set helper classes for first and last element of this "list"
        parent.find(' > div:first-child').addClass('flex-position-first');
        parent.find(' > div:last-child').addClass('flex-position-last');

        //initialize positioning variables
        var parent_offset = parent.offset();
        var max_vertical_space = 0;
        var row_count = 0;

        //for each element in the query
        parent.find(' > div').each(function (index) {

          //get element metrics
          var element_metrics = $(this).offset();
          element_metrics.top -= parent_offset.top;
          element_metrics.left -= parent_offset.left;
          element_metrics.height = $(this).height();
          element_metrics.vertical_space = element_metrics.height + element_metrics.top;

          //increment row_count if element is below previous elements and set helper classes for row[first|last]
          if(element_metrics.top > max_vertical_space) {
            $(this).addClass('flex-position-rowfirst');
            $(this).prev().addClass('flex-position-rowlast');
            row_count++;
          }
          //reset max_vertical_space if needed
          if(element_metrics.vertical_space > max_vertical_space) {
            max_vertical_space = element_metrics.vertical_space;
          }
          //
          $(this).addClass('flex-row-' + row_count);

        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.each($('ul'), function() {
    var w = $(this).width();
    var totalwidth = 0;
    $.each($(this).children('li'), function() {
        var elw = $(this).width();
        if (totalwidth == 0) {
           $(this).addClass('left');
        }
        totalwidth += elw;
        if (Math.abs(w - totalwidth) < 1) {
           $(this).addClass('right');
           totalwidth = 0;
        }
    })
})
```